# Convert Apple Maps coordinates in universal format

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to convert the coordinates displayed in Apple Maps as

```
38,89016° N, 1,22427° O
```

(German notation)

or

```
38.89016° N, 1.22427° E
```

(English notation)

into something like

```
38.89016, 1.22427
```

(Expected result)

but only if the user did enter a expression matching this pattern and not if the user enters something like an address or anything in the input field.

Therefore I would be using PHP [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

However I have difficulties building a matching regex and was wondering if someone found a solution to this already?

*I already tried different regex variations on my own already, this one was the last one I experimented with but did not work as expected as it did not replace anything:

```
$regex = "/^(\d{1,2}[.,]\d+)\s*[°]\s*(N|S)\s*[,]\s*(\d{1,3}[.,]\d+)\s*[°]\s*(E|O|W)$/i";
$output = preg_replace($regex, "$1, $3", $input);
```

I have a regex to verify, the expected result is in the correct form which does work as expected, though I wasn't able to modify it for the replacement:

```
/^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
(-?\d*)[.,](\d*)° [NS], (-?\d*)[.,](\d*)° [EOW]
```

with replacement string `$1.$2, $3.$4`.

```php
$re = '/(-?\d*)[.,](\d*)° [NS], (-?\d*)[.,](\d*)° [EOW]/m';
$str = '38,89016° N, 1,22427° O
38.89016° N, 1.22427° E
-38.89016° S, 1.22427° E
Address: Some street, 123, 21
';
$subst = "$1.$2, $3.$4";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

Output:

```
The result of the substitution is 38.89016, 1.22427
38.89016, 1.22427
-38.89016, 1.22427
Address: Some street, 123, 21
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/JgBeOH/2)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is great! However, it does't yet replace the comma (german notation) with a point. Would it be also possible to add this to the regex?

Comment: @TimNikischin, my bad missed that in question. Amended answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your precise and fast answer! You really did some great help!